# Show rows in table with cells name attribute containing string from input (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to have keyup function that would show only rows matching the input text by cell that spans on multiple rows.
Consider following table:

```
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>Key1</td>
        <td name='Key1'> dummy1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td name='Key1'> dummy2 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>Key2</td>
        <td name='Key2'> dummy3 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td name='Key2'> dummy4 </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gugy7r1o/)

Here each row has second td tag with name that matches its "parent" column text. So when I type 'Key1' at the input field I would like it to show only dummy1 and dummy2. Is it possible in jquery?

Comment: Yes, it's possible in jQuery. See the `:contains()` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to display the rows that has a matching `name`. If this is wrong, please elaborate more, then I can update it.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/gugy7r1o/33/

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   $('tr').hide();
   $("td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) != -1; }).parent().show().next().show();
   });
});
```

Comment: Might it be case insensitive?

Comment: @griboedov see the updated code above and example : https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/gugy7r1o/33/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your issue, assuming you always want the first column to show. https://jsfiddle.net/gugy7r1o/2/

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>Key1</td>
        <td name='Key1' class="data"> dummy1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td name='Key1' class="data"> dummy2 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>Key2</td>
        <td name='Key2' class="data"> dummy3 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td name='Key2' class="data"> dummy4 </td>
     </tr>
</table>

.data{
    display:none;
}

var theData = $('td.data');

var input = $('#myInput').on('keyup', function(){
    theData.hide();
    var value = input.val();

    var matches = theData.filter('[name="'+value+'"]');
    matches.show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend using `<ul>` to wrap each key in as tables should be used for data structure (Forgive me if that is what it is being used for).

Secondly, just attach an on `keyup` event to the search box and then find matches based on the id. See example below:

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gugy7r1o/31/)

It is also worth mentioning that it could be useful attaching a `timeout` to the `keyup` event if you end up having large amounts of rows so that only one filter is fired for fast typers!